# Sorting array by other array values

Tags: php, arrays

Here's the idea: a user enters his ZIP code. 
Based on the inserted ZIP code, I get an array of ZIP codes (distance ordered).

Next I want to order an existing array of ZIP codes based on the distance ordered array.

So basically I have two arrays:

1. Array which should be ordered

   array(2) {
     [0]=>
     string(4) "2018"
     [1]=>
     string(4) "2500"
   }
2. Distance ordered array

   array(247) {
     [0]=>
     string(4) "2000"
     [1]=>
     string(4) "2500"
     [2]=>
     string(4) "2050"
     [2]=>
     string(4) "2018"

In this example, my array (number 1) should be ordered like so: [0]  => 2500, [1] => 2018

How can I manage this?

Comment: use rsort($array);

Comment: @Ish I honestly don't see how this would solve my problem. Can u provide more information?

Comment: @PaulCrovella I've read the post. There's so much information that I wouldn't know where to start or what is useful for in my case. Care to answer something more hands-on?

Comment: Do I understand correct that the values of array 1 should be ordered by the position they're in in array 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `array_intersect()` to get only the values of the second array that are also in the first array. And as the function preserves the keys - and so the order -, you only have to renumber them.

```
$a1=array(2018,2500);
$a2=array(2000,2500,2050,2018);

$a3=array_intersect( $a2 , $a1 );

echo print_r($a3,true);
```

Result:

> Array (
>       [1] => 2500
>       [3] => 2018 )